# php artisan tinker isn't giving any output

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm running `php artisan tinker` followed by `App\Project::all();` but upon pressing enter, I just get redirected to my project directory as opposed to displaying all records in the database?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey! What's in your App\Project model?

Comment: @LucyTurtle how can I check that?  I'm new to this, sorry :D

Comment: well you would have to open up the file in your project directory then app\Project. This should be a model file that you/a team member wrote since this is not a file that is in a base Laravel project

Comment: @greyskies Add a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 3):

I have php 7.3 on my machine installed via homebrew.

I have to add a config file.

```
nano ~/.config/psysh/config.php

<?php return [ 'usePcntl' => false,]; ?>
```

After doing this I am able to use tinker

Comment: Worked for me, but what are ramifications of this?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `App`.

```
Project::all()
```

Can you try this.

Comment: May I know whats version of laravel are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using's 5.7.25

Comment: Can you please try with `App\Project::where('id', 1)->first()`

Comment: Tell me wat hapen

Comment: same result happened